# DataTemplate seems to cache bound custom object resulting in wrong values

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate, treelistview

I have a custom `TreeListView` (based on a `TreeView`) in my WPF-Application. The `ItemSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Node>` where `Node` is a custom class that is based on a `TreeListViewItem` and therefore a `TreeItem`. It contains the values that should be displayed.

The Binding of the columns to the values in the `Node` works when new Nodes are loaded (I implemented a lazyload, the ItemSource changes often (new `Node`s added) and so does the UI), but when a value in the Node changes, the value in the UI doesn't change.

I created a `DataTemplate` with triggers to test the behaviour:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate_Speicherplatz">
    <TextBlock Name="tbSpeicherplatz" TextAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RecSpeicherplatz, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type k:Node}}}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsProcessing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RecSpeicherplatz, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type k:Node}}}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsProcessing, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="..."/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

This results in the following behaviour: while `IsProcessing` is true, the text in the UI is "...". When `IsProcessing` changes to false, the old value of `RecSpeicherplatz` is shown even though the variable has been changed in the `Node`.

Could somebody please explain why it is behaving like that and how to solve this?

Comment: Does the Node class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Do you raise the PropertyChanged event when the property RecSpeicherplatz changes?

Comment: @RaúlNuño thanks a lot, I didn't even think about that Node itself has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It works now.

Comment: @RaúlNuño I will accept if at answer if you post it as such

Comment: Ok, in fact I posted it as an answer at first instance.

Comment: Did you delete it or how can it be that I didn't see the answer? I refreshed several times and visited other questions

Comment: Yes, I deleted it and then posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Node class implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Do you raise the PropertyChanged event when the property RecSpeicherplatz changes?